# PHP/Laravel Take json from string

Tags: php, json, laravel

I call an API and the response is like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created 
Date: Tue, 12 Jun 2018 13:13:34 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.x (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=id; path=/; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 114
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json

{"id":"id_code|id_code|id_code","error":{"code":0,"message":"message"}}
```

What I want to do is take only the json part from final:

```
{"id":"id_code|id_code|id_code","error":{"code":0,"message":"message"}}
```

Can I do this using PHP?

Thank you!

Comment: could you show ur calling part code?

Comment: Are you useing gazzele??

Comment: @Davit you mean [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/)?

Comment: [http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) lhis package??

Comment: **$response->getBody()->getContents()**

Answer (score 1):

You can get the contents of the response with `$response->getBody()->getContent()`, or you can cast the body to a string. From there if it is in JSON format you can decode it as normal:

```
// this works
$jsonResults = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContent(), true);

// so does this
$jsonResults = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.